# Good Laptop for Little Sister (12 years old)

Tags: windows, laptop, netbook

The max I am looking to spend is $200. She doesn't need anything fancy

Comment: You don't have *any* criteria to help narrow this down, other than "mac" and that the user will be 12 years old?

Comment: At least post a price range, otherwise you'll get suggestions way out there.

Comment: The max I am looking to spend is $200. She doesn't need anything fancy.

Comment: This is way too localised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the lines of what Stephen Jennings said, you should probably get her a netbook. If you're looking for deals there are some Black Friday ones [here](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=5378), there's a couple of netbooks listed in it for 200.

Answer (score 5):

From the experience with my own sister, I can almost guarantee you that as long as the computer can open a web browser, run AIM, and play Flash games, then she will be perfectly happy.  Unless you have other uses in mind, a simple Windows netbook would be a great and inexpensive fit.

I imagine that she would consider small and lightweight to be added bonuses, not limiting factors.  She'll easily be able to carry it around and use it anywhere, and there is definitely something to be said for the "cute" factor.

Comment: What do u recommend?

Comment: The models change often enough that you may as well just walk into Best Buy or look on New Egg or Amazon, find a model that runs Windows that has the size of screen you would like, and purchase.  The differences between different netbooks is usually just screen size, hard drive size, and keyboard size (some have ridiculously tiny keys that are impossible to touch-type on).

Answer (score 2):

The $200 price limit means you won't be getting anything brand new.  Even netbooks are usually more than that.  I would watch Craigslist for a good deal.  Anything with a P4 or better would probably serve her purposes just fine.  As someone above said, anything that can surf the web and play Youtube videos will probably suffice.

Comment: http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=5378 couple of netbooks new for 200 there

Answer (score 1):

My daughter (12) inherited my Dell Inspiron 8200 (ancient, but usable with 2GB Ram and dedicated graphics) .. it works for most things, even simpler games.

---

A decent & recent laptop can be baught for 600CHF (Swiss Franks) .. I assume that's 400-500$, despite the 1:1 exchange rate ..

---

So .. buy a used laptop from a hobbyist (like me) .. or get a cheap new one (more expensive, but also more powerfull) ..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a netbook.  I have an ASUS Eee PC, which works great and is really light and quite durable.  I would suggest buying it using an Amex to double the warranty to two years.  New price for the 1000HA (my model) is $300, so you might want to try to find a used one.

Answer (score 0):

My clients have had good luck with both Refurb MacBooks [Refurbished Mac - Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/mac?mco=MTM3NDY2NTI) and iBooks from [MacOfAllTrades.com](http://www.macofalltrades.com/glossary_ibook_a/204.htm)

Comment: I dont think we will buy a Mac though.

Comment: Then why tag the article with "mac"?

Comment: If you're not looking for a mac, then edit your tags.